# Ошибка сайта в Опере

Tags: mysql, браузер

Есть сайт, который работает нормально в последнем Хроме.
При просмотре сайта с Оперы или мобильного Хрома выходит такая ошибка. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Таблица на которую он ругается имеет два поля ip, time и не содержит уникального столбца

Comment: У вас не ошибка браузера, а ошибка связаная с неправильным построением вами sql-запроса, у вас же ip сравнивается с пусто. Скорее всего опера немного иначе передаёт информацию про ip адрес. Проверяйте почему у вас ip = пусто.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего проблема в том что вы берете IP пользователя который зашел на сайт каким то способом который доступен только для Chrome Desktop, потому что на скрине видно что в запрос не подставилось значение IP, проверяйте на сервере перед тем как подставлять IP есть ли он вообще, если нет - тогда не делать запрос или вставлять по умолчанию какой то.